# Insert PHP code after nth element with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css-selectors, insertafter

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container"><div class="wrapper">
    <p>Some Content/p>
    <p>More Content</p>
    <p>An Image</p>
    <p>More Content</p>
    <p>Even More Content</p>
    <p>A Second Image</p>
</div></div>
```

I want to insert some PHP after the second paragraph. I have a [JSFiddle that is working without the PHP code](http://jsfiddle.net/phej/q7a6twzw/), using:

```
$('.wrapper p').eq(1).after('<div>hello</div>');
```

But as soon as I add the PHP code it [stops working](http://jsfiddle.net/phej/1x94b9zw/) using:

```
$('.wrapper p').eq(1).after('<div>hello <?php wds_social_media_icons(); ?></div>');
```

**What's going on? Can I just not use PHP with .after?**

Comment: PHP is server side, javascript is client side, so you cannot do it that way.

Comment: You can't add a php code inside JQuery

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Comment: Not necessarily @Matteo - if the js file is processed by PHP then this is perfectly valid, the only question would be what the php function does

Comment: If you're trying to run the PHP after the page has loaded it will not work. You'll need some AJAX to run the function and return information or you'll have to store the info in a session variable and echo it out. from the looks of it you'll want to use AJAX to get the result of the function.

Comment: I have all the logic in a separate file and wds_social_media_icons(); just calls that logic. If I can't do it like this, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, it cannot be interpreted by the client browser.
You need to put all your PHP logic on your server.

Comment: I have all the logic in a separate file and wds_social_media_icons(); just calls that logic. If I can't do it like this, how can I do it?

Comment: What does `wds_social_media_icons();` do ? Does it generate some html code to show social icons ? What do you want to do ?